# Pact-JS Support for Corporate Proxies

Tags: http-proxy, pact, pact-node

I am trying to configure the latest version (@pact-foundation/pact 12.3.0) of pact-js to verify pacts, while behind a corporate proxy.

However, when I am running Pact Verify with pact-js, I can see the requests to my providerBaseUrl are not going through my proxy and are failing.

I have followed the instructions here https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/ssl#proxies, but configuration of these http_proxy variables does not appear to be affecting the internal pact dsl verifier traffic.

I have also not had success in this version of pact-js using a global agent; however, this technique did work in earlier 9.x versions of pact-js.

I opened a discussion for the same topic here: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/discussions/1187

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had a better answer - it looks like a bug! Thanks for the detailed discussion.